# Get the length of a sharepoint list column in a calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

How to get the length of a list column in another column? e.g. I want to get the total number of characters in the column "Name" of the list, so I have created a calculated column called "Name Length" and applied the formula LEN(Name) to this computed column, but this column shows 0 for all the items in the list. Am i using the wrong formula or something? Please suggest?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010, can that be the reason??